# How to count the number of installed packages, including dependencies

Tags: npm, count, dependencies, package

Is there an easy way to obtain a count of installed npm packages, both global and local to an application?

For example, after running `create-react-app` [1], I get screens-full of packages and dependencies installed when I enter the `npm ls` command.

How to find a **count** ("cardinality") of said packages and dependencies eludes me. Tyvm, Keith :^)

References:

1. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: As a work-around, I've been doing a copy n' paste into some editor, followed by a line count.

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
npm ls --parseable | wc -l
```

Comment: This seems to be one more than the true number of dependencies (based on the output of running `npm install`)

Comment: fyi for anyone skeptical of this flag, --parseable implicitly dedupes your dependencies; it's a list of the existing installation directories in your node_modules folder, including nested installation folders. deduped installations are automatically elevated to the root directory

Comment: In case you prefer to count distinct dependencies (ignoring different versions of the same dependency across the graph), check the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77880048/6103242

Answer (score 9):

In order to count unique dependencies you should exclude deduped packages:

```
npm ls | sed '/deduped$/d' | wc -l
```

Comment: Why does this produce a different result than the `--parseable` flag on `npm ls`?

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of `npm`, it should list a count of how many packages were installed/added after running `npm install` (or `npm i`):

[image: npm install output]

In this case the project I'm working has only a few top-level `dependencies` and `devDependencies` listed in the `package.json` but `281` is actual count of all packages added. I posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239177/difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-audit-counts) in the hopes of getting more information on the audit count discrepancy.

So I think what I listed above is the simplest approach for getting the count for a specific project. However let's break your question down a little more...

#### Count for a Project

See above (basically remove your `node_modules` directory and run `npm i`).

#### Count for a Specific Package

The OP's question touches on this with `create-react-app`. So what if I want to see the total package count for `create-react-app`?

1. Start from a fresh directory.
2. Run `npm i create-react-app`.
3. See the output...

[image: create-react-app in fresh directory]

Why create a new directory you ask? Because an existing project might already have some of `create-react-app`s dependencies installed, thus causing the `added` count to differ:

[image: create-react-app in existing project]

#### Count Global Packages

I don't have a great answer to this one yet (but I'm happy to update the answer if we come across one). Because global installs (`npm i -g ...`) aren't store in a global `package.json`, I don't think you can run `npm i -g` by itself to get the count. It seems one approach might be to do what the OP mentioned, meaning...

1. Run `npm ls`.
2. Copy the output into a text editor and do a line count.

And I'm sure some bash wizard could automate this by piping the output of `npm ls` to another CLI command or two, e.g. (`npm ls | count-lines`).

One thing to note here though is that I'm *not 100% sure the number of lines is a one-to-one mapping for the number of packages*. I seem to recall instances where `npm` will `list` a dependency under a package but then put parentheses next to it indicating that it was installed only once (but listed multiple times), is symlinked, etc. So again, not sure of a great solution for globals yet.

**UPDATE:**

`npm ls` will list certain dependencies with `deduped` next to them like so:

```
loud-rejection@1.6.0 deduped
```

So `npm ls` with a straight line count isn't a perfect approach unless you delete `deduped` lines and take into account other flags like this one.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` is the only way I've found so far to get the number I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This will output the number of **distinct** production (not dev) dependencies, traversing an **entire** graph (that is, it'll **not** count different versions of the same dependency):

```
echo $(($(npm ls -P --depth Infinity --parseable | sed 's/@[0-9].*$//g' | uniq | wc -l) - 1))
```

I. e. if a graph has both `resolve@1.22.2` and `resolve@1.22.4`, it will be counted only **once**.

To verify correctness, remove `node_modules` dir, then run `npm i` and check the beginning of the output saying something like `added XXX packages, and ...`

---

If you'd like to include different versions of the same dependency into the count, this is the slightly modified command:

```
echo $(($(npm ls -P --depth Infinity --parseable | uniq | wc -l) - 1))
```

###### Tested on:

npm 9.8.1
pnpm 8.11.0
node v18.18.2
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)
macOS 13.6.3

P. S.
Both of the commands work with `pnpm` as well, however the output doesn't matches the output of `pnpm install`... I don't see enough economic incentive to be solving that mis(t)ery. Please leave a comment if you see it otherwise.