# Difference between `npm install` and `npm audit` counts?

Tags: javascript, npm

After the recent addition of `npm audit` (for auditing dependencies) I noticed a huge discrepancy between how many packages are `added` (installed in `node_modules`) and how many are `audited` by `npm`. Here's an example:

[image: npm install output]

Here are my questions:

- Am I correct that `281` is the total number of packages installed?
- Why is `npm` auditing so many more packages than the ones in my project?

It makes sense to me that `npm` might have to go back out and `audit` other package versions if it finds a vulnerability, but in this case it `found 0 vulnerabilities` so why the additional work?

**UPDATE:**

I think there's a little confusion about top-level vs sub dependencies. Run the following commands to reproduce a similar discrepancy:

```
mkdir test-npm-count-discrepancy
cd test-npm-count-discrepancy
npm init
npm i standard-version
```

Notice that (at the time of writing this) `200+` dependencies are `added` (i.e. `standard-version` and all its sub dependencies) but `1000+` packages are `audited`. Just to re-iterate, the main question from above is "why is `npm` auditing more packages than what's actually installed?".

Comment: Isn't npm checking nested packages?

Comment: It is but `281` is the count of top-level + nested packages (I think). There's less than 10 dependencies listed in my actual `package.json`.

Comment: considering *281* is the number of local modules you have if you do `npm ls --depth=0` and doing a `npm ls` will show you the list of nested modules that got auto installed along with those modules.

Comment: @RaktimBiswas no `npm ls --depth=0` will only list my 8 _explicitly_ installed packages. `npm ls` lists exactly 281 if you account for `deduped` lines. I'm 99% sure the answer to my first question is yes, `281` is the total number (top-level and nested). There is definitely a discrepancy what `audit` looks at and what's installed locally.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:
 - the community, without a link to something like a dependency list or your package.json, wouldn't really be able to say so. However, if in your package file only has a few, then it still is normal most of the time. You may have installed 12 yourself, but NPM auto-installs most, if not all, dependencies for your app's dependencies for you. It helps things speed up your workflow.

For the second question:
 - as mentioned in my response to the first question, it is auditing both the ones you installed and the ones that were installed automatically so that the ones you installed work properly.

For the third question:
 - It always checks for vulnerabilities marked by developers so you can have the latest version which is, most of the time, the least buggy, the most functional, and most secure.

Edit:
The whole point of `npm install` is to update current dependencies and install new ones to the directory. The point of `npm audit` is to check for dependencies that have updates marked to fix security issues.

Edit 2:
I think I've got it: it could be auditing the installed dependencies for production, your dependencies, and the dev-dependencies to warn you that one of your dependencies was built insecurely by the developer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but please see the comments above. It's definitely not a nested vs top-level dependency issue. I understand you're request for an example though and while I can't share the repo from the screenshot, I can share some minimal `npm` commands to reproduce the discrepancy.

Comment: @SkipJack, Yeah I know what you mean with not being able to share the package file. However, the audit should be looking at everything from what you installed via the package and what was installed with those dependencies so that they work and so on and so forth. But the whole point of "npm install" is to update current dependencies and install new ones to the directory. The point of "npm audit" is to check for dependencies that have updates marked to fix security issues.

Comment: Please see the __UPDATE__ section of the question and try those steps. I think it will clarify things a bit and I do understand the the point of both commands.

Comment: @SkipJack I think I might have it. Not entirely sure: but it probably includes dev-dependencies from those dependencies and so on and so forth: not just production dependencies. Usually, dev-dependencies don't need to be installed: just production. Thus causing the smaller installed number and larger audited number.

Comment: That could definitely be it. If `npm` is remotely auditing those packages' dev dependencies, then that would explain a discrepancy in counts. If you find some hard evidence that that’s the case (e.g. source code or docs) then I recommend you update your answer and I’ll be happy to accept it if it all checks out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @SkipJack "npm audit is a new command that performs a moment-in-time security review of your project’s dependency tree" ([source](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/173719309445/npm-audit-identify-and-fix-insecure)) A project dependency tree would include all its production and developer dependencies. Therefore, it would continuously build onto branches of the base project tree into the 1000+ audits you've been getting. Let me know if I should try to find a little more to the word of it being and not the basis of meaning.

Comment: Run `npm audit --production` and see if the number drops back down to 281.

Comment: Update: tried it; it only removed about 100 for me out of about 4000, so that isn't the answer.  Deduped ls returns 387 (367 for `--production`).  Interestingly, the number audited seems to be about one order of magnitude greater than the number installed in these cases.  I wonder if that could be a hint.  Maybe what it does is checks the currently installed version and then recurses down all available versions to find "unfixed" vulnerabilities?  That would be my guess.

Comment: Or maybe it recurses "up" from the base version recording vulnerabilities and nixing them when it finds a fix.  Either way, I suspect this is the answer.  It allows them to deduplicate their storage of vulnerabilities (they only record the vulnerability once and the fix once).

Comment: I was looking for some information about the same discrepancy as the OP mentioned. I'd like to add to this discussion what I'm seeing when I do an npm install in my SharePoint Framework (SPFx) project:
added 2184 packages from 1212 contributors and audited 584933 packages in 57.953s.
In my case it audited 250x the number of installed packages... I wonder if the number of audited packages is even correct. It would take a huge amount of time to actually audit this number of packages in under a couple of seconds (which it took).